# Bower/grunt keeps removing one of my packages

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I got several packages loaded. But each time I run `grunt serve` or `grunt` it removes one from my `index.html` file

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-csv-import/dist/angular-csv-import.js"></script>
```

My `bower.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.2.27",
    "json3": "^3.3.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.1.1",
    "angular-animate": "^1.2.27",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.2.27",
    "angular-messages": "^1.2.27",
    "angular-resource": "^1.2.27",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.2.27",
    "angular-touch": "^1.2.27",
    "underscore": "~1.7.0",
    "angular-csv-import": "~0.0.14",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "angular-rangeslider": "~0.0.11",
    "highcharts-ng": "~0.0.7",
    "highcharts-release": "~4.0.4",
    "ng-csv": "~0.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.27",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.2.27"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

It's also in my `karma.conf.js` file.

Why is it removing angular-csv-import from my `index.html` file?

Comment: Did you install it via `bower install -S ng-csv`? or `--save`

Comment: I use bower install angular-csv-import --save

Comment: How do you know bower removes it? Does the module not work?

Comment: Well something is removing it. Everything works with minifying, running a server etc, except with this single package.

Comment: Well how do you know it's not working? Did you look through the minified `index.html` or is the module not working?

Comment: Module is not working. Console says it's missing ngcsv package.

Comment: `angular-csv-import` is not the same as `ng-csv`. Are you sure you're not mistaking them for each other?

Comment: No, I'm not mistaking. I'm using both (upload/download)